# Help with flash builder4.5 crashing on startup(Mac)

Tags: eclipse, flash, macos, adobe, flash-builder

Please my flash builder always crashes on startup. I have never used the application before because it always crashes.When i open it, it tries to start up but crashes and creates a log report in a file. The contents of this file is here --> http://pastebin.com/a0kNni2L

I didn't post it here because it was a bit too long. Please can anyone help me with whats going on and a possible solution? I would really appreciate your input..

Thanks

EDIT: PLEASEEEE someone should help me out

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations. You have experienced your first workspace corruption. I was working on a project recently where this was a daily occurrence.

Delete your workspace entry from the prefs file found in:

> `~/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/cascaded/308971/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`

Note, the .settings folder will be hidden from the Finder.

You may want to try deleting the prefs file altogether.

In future, try and keep your projects outside the default workspace location (eg. on your Desktop, or whatever) so that if the workspace gets corrupted again, you can easily get up and running with your projects once the workspace is reset without having to reconfigure each and every project (just import them again).

Good luck!

Comment: here isint a .settings file. I went through the terminal and ddnt see it. I also ran a command to display all hidden files on the finder but still ddnt see it...

Answer (score 0):

Is the user account you log in to your Mac with an "Administrator" account?  You might want to check permissions on the Flash Builder 4.5 folder (located in the Applications folder).  I seem to remember a problem with earlier versions of Flex where my user account had read-only access to the application.

How recently did you run the Flash Builder installer?  Did you receive any error messages during the install?

Comment: I didnt receive any error messages during install, am also running from my main account

Answer (score 0):

i had to delete the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` package in the `Users/[YOUR_NAME]/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/.metadata/.plugins`

after that flash builder startednormally and the projects were still in their workspace..

`.metadata` folder is invisible, so you have to run following line in terminal to show hidden files in the finder:

```
//show hidden files
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall -HUP Finder

//hide hidden files
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall -HUP Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing happened to me and I managed to fix it by searching in workbench.xml for the line that actually provokes the crash at startup. There were two  nodes that I deleted from workbench.xml and everything worked fine after that. I encourage everyone to make a script that regulary saves the workbench folder so that, in such a case, a revert would be possible.

**General steps to fix this issue**

1. open this file: "c:\Users[youruser]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.metadata.plugins\workbench.xml" and search for nodes that look like this:

*< editor id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.editors.actionscript.ActionScriptEditor" name="[somefile].as" partName="Group0.as" path="[somepath]" title="[somefile].as" tooltip="[somefile].as" workbook="DefaultEditorWorkbook">
< input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInputFactory" path="[somepath].as"/>
< editorState selectionHorizontalPixel="0" selectionLength="3" selectionOffset="23" selectionTopPixel="0"/>
    < /editor>*

Please note it might look a bit different, but the < editor>< /editor> nodes should be there.
**Delete all < editor> nodes from there.**

Save workbench.xml and start Fb again.

- if that does not work, make sure Flash builder is closed, then delete file workbench.xml from 
  c:\Users[youruser]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\
- if that does not work, make sure Flash builder is closed, then delete the whole folder: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench" from 
  c:\Users[youruser]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.metadata.plugins
- if that does not work, make sure Flash builder is closed and delete the whole .metadata folder from c:\Users[youruser]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\
- and if THAT does not work, as far as I know, you should reinstall Adobe Flash Builder.